# Bookshelves: Einstein's place

Tags: pattern, visual

Another picture of my bookshelves. I can't work out where to shelve my puzzle book. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Rather than adding Stangroom's book, if you removed the Pollan and Harris ones and replaced them with another one by Rovelli then there'd be something of interest. I suspect that's pure coincidence, though.

Comment: Very possibly. You might find quite a few coincidences if you were allowed to change four elements of the puzzle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place it just to the left of

> The Rights of Woman.

> This way, the titles are in reverse alphabetical order by second letter, the preferred way to shelve books in, um, your house?
>  - First letters: ESIAI (E) TRAG
>  - Second letters: VUTPM (I) HEDA

Answer (score 1):

> Put it between *It Must Be Beautiful* and *A Place of My Own*. It will look best there, since it's the same height as *The Rights of Woman*.

Comment: Good try - but who arranges their books so they look good?

Comment: @MichaelMaggs Anyone who has only ten books, I guess. I was led to this answer by the [tag:visual] tag, which implies (to me) that the visual aspect of the picture (and not just the titles and authors) is important somehow.

Comment: From MichaelMaggs's previous puzzles of this kind, it seems evident that he has a lot more than 10 books. (And a pretty interesting selection of 'em, too.)

Comment: I've used the visual tag as it could be anything in the photo: titles and authors, of course, but potentially anything else too